# Jasperreport NoSuchMethodError JasperDesign.setOrientation

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

In a project using DynamicReport and Jasperreports, with this code:

```
JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilderSubreport = generateSubReport(...);
...
JasperReport jasperReport = jasperReportBuilderSubreport.toJasperReport(); //Exception line
```

the execution throws an Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setOrientation(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/OrientationEnum;)V
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ReportTransform.page(ReportTransform.java:220)
    ...
```

The pom.xml:

```
...
  <dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>

..
  <dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
<artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

...

Do you know which is the problem? Thanks

Comment: did you check if those versions are compatible?

Comment: yes, they are http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/requirements.html

Comment: The problem comes from another library which uses jasperreports 3.5.2 I have solved the problem using <exclusion>. thanks